# What is a word for the art of making watches/clocks

Tags: single-word-requests

In French, such an interest/profession is referred to as **horlogerie** from **horloge** (watch/clock). I am just wondering if there is an equivalent term in English?

Comment: http://translate.google.com/#fr|en|horlogerie watchmaking  
Dictionary  
    noun  
    watchmaking  
    **horology**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are simply called [watchmakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchmaker) or [clockmakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockmaker).

Answer (score 8):

The English term is *horology*, and one who engages in the profession is a *horologist*.

Comment: [1611](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/cotgrave/530.html), horlogue: a clocke, or dyall; also I would find this [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clockmaker%2Chorologist%2C+watchmaker&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) rather showing.

Comment: @Unreason: 'Clockmaker' and 'watchmaker' are of course the more usual terms, but I was responding to the OP's request for an 'equiavelent' term. 'Horologist' does have the advantage of covering one who mends and repairs (and, yes, takes an interest in) both small and large timepieces.

Comment: Oh, I do like your answer and I do think it is good; I was just trying to add more to it. Ever since I saw BBC's Longitude I find the whole subject of horology really interesting.

Comment: @BarrieEngland I'm not sure how it's "equivalent" - it shares a root, but it's not a cognate - a cognate to a word ending in "erie" should end in "ery" not "logy".

Answer (score 1):

[Horology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horology) is actually the art or science of measuring time. And the people interested in horology are called horologists

Comment: It's also 'the construction of horologes' (OED).

Comment: You wrote your answer as if it is a reply to Barrie's, but failed to mention that 'people interested in horology are called *horologists*. That term is used both by people who deal professionally with timekeeping apparatus (watchmakers, clockmakers), as well as aficionados and scholars of horology.'